# laser_scan_matcher always diverges

Tags: ros, lidar, laser, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed laser_scan_matcher and run the demo bag along with the demo.launch. The laser pose directly starts jumping around and goes totally instable. Same happens with the demo_gmapping.launch.
Am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229252/laser_scan_matcher-always-diverges/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was playing the bag and then launching demo.launch. Did not notice that demo.launch also plays the bag file, which has led to inconsistency.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1